# netsh interface ipv4 show config doesn't match Windows 10 IP assignment in Settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, ip, dhcp

I have set a static IP address using the netsh command interface.

The IP address is indeed statically set. This is verified by being able to communicate with a device expecting the static IP address. It also verified by running the show config command, which lists DHCP as disabled and the proper IP address.

[image]

However... the IP assignment inside of Windows 10 Settings  > Network & Internet > Ethernet > Unidentified Network > IP Settings is reading "Automatic (DHCP)".

[image]

Though the IPv4 address DOES match the static IP set.

[image]

**Can anyone offer an explanation of why this is the case? How can I resolve it via command prompt? I worry problems will arise from these inconsistent values.**

Comment: Compare your first picture with IPCONFIG /ALL  and make sure your first picture matches with ipconfig.  The second picture says "unidentified network" and so may not be reliable.

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestion. I compared and they do match. I am not concerned about the "Unidentified Network" naming, as I've noticed this behavior when connecting directly via Ethernet port to certain devices.

Comment: So then your network configuration is fine since it matches with IPconfig.

Comment: @John Any explanation for why Settings GUI IP Assignment doesn't match?

Comment: I cannot say for sure. When I use the icon in the System Tray, it takes me to Windows 10 Network Settings and that just gives me the IP and related settings, not whether DHCP.  For this, I just use IPconfig to be certain.

Comment: @John How strange. I appreciate the help and will operate as if the network config is good, as you suggested. Hopefully, someone might still answer the question; it is a mystery I would like solved.

Comment: My machines work perfectly and all 3 do the same thing, so I think what I have given you is the answer.

Comment: @John It's (greatly appreciated) reassurance, yes... But it does not answer my post's question: "Can anyone offer an explanation of why this is the case?"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This means your DNS server is assigned by DHCP. If you configure DNS manually, then you will see the picture below:
[image]

[image]

This IP assignment settings is related with DNS configuration.